# NullPointerException on OverlapBehavior in SLD

Tags: geoserver

When rendering raster data, GeoServer (v2.15.0) is reporting a NullPointerException on the OverlapBehavior specified in the SLD :

```
...
<Rule>
    <RasterSymbolizer>
        <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>

        <OverlapBehavior>
            <AVERAGE/>
        </OverlapBehavior>
        ...
```

The stacktrace produced by GeoServer :

```
...
java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
    at org.opengis.style.OverlapBehavior.valueOf(OverlapBehavior.java:30)
    at org.geotools.styling.RasterSymbolizerImpl.setOverlap(RasterSymbolizerImpl.java:380)
    at org.geotools.xml.styling.SLDParser.parseRasterSymbolizer(SLDParser.java:1317)
...
```

I looked at the AVERAGE-value, and according to the docs and the source-code it should be ok...

```
@XmlElement("OverlapBehavior")
public enum OverlapBehavior {
    LATEST_ON_TOP,
    EARLIEST_ON_TOP,
    AVERAGE,
    RANDOM;

    private OverlapBehavior() {
    }
}
```

Why is GeoServer throwing this error ? On our test-environment this SLD is working just fine...
Why is the error messaging saying that the Name is null ?

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [`RasterSymbolizerImpl` class](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/styling/RasterSymbolizerImpl.java) I'm guessing it's expecting a `literal` expression such as `<Literal>AVERAGE</Literal>` rather than an `<AVERAGE />` tag.

From the JavaDocs

> @param overlap the expression which evaluates to LATEST_ON_TOP, EARLIEST_ON_TOP, AVERAGE or RANDOM

So it looks like the [GeoServer docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#overlapbehavior) are out of sync with the actual code implementation (not least because they say the feature is not implemented) - if you find this does work then please [update the documentation](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/doc/en/user/source/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.rst) to match reality.

Comment: Just gave it at try... and this resulted in an error validating the SLD : line 19: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Literal'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":LATEST_ON_TOP, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":EARLIEST_ON_TOP, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":AVERAGE, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":RANDOM}' is expected.

Comment: don't worry about validation, does it work

Comment: just tried it on our test environment... it didn't break anything ; as soon as I have the opportunity I will try this in production to check if the error messages we see there are going away...